# Заполнение одного `datatable` с помощью другого `datatable`

Tags: c#, ado.net

Добрый день! Есть два `datatable` и `data_list`. `datatable` берёт данные из запроса sql. А `data_list` из таблицы `datatable`. Если я добавлю в `datatable` ещё одну строку, то как сделать чтобы в `data_list` добавился только новые данные из `datatable?`

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cn))
            {
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {

                        adapter.Fill(dt);   
                  if (DataList == null)
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(DataList);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
```

Comment: Может поможете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, не нужно два раза считывать из БД одни и те же данные:

```
adapter.Fill(dt);
...
adapter.Fill(DataList);
```

Лучше скопировать данные методом [`Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable.copy(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (DataList == null)
    DataList = dt.Copy();
```

Если нужно добавить данные из одного `DataTable` к другому или обновить их, то следует использовать метод [`Merge`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable.merge(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DataList.Merge(dt);
```

При этом должны быть заданы первичные ключи в обоих дататейблах. Для этого при создании адаптера нужно задать свойство [`MissingSchemaAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.missingschemaaction(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
```

Возможно, нужно ещё изменить свойство [`FillLoadOption`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.fillloadoption(v=vs.110).aspx) на подходящее.

Во-вторых, вам просто-напросто не нужны два `DataTable`. Оставьте один, в него и считывайте данные. Метод `Fill` при наличии первичных ключей будет обновлять уже имеющиеся данные (или считывать полностью при их отсутствии).

Естественно, первичные ключи должны быть заданы в базе данных.

Comment: а как можно добавить строку(string) в `datatable` как *row*  и обновить datatable?

Comment: @propro17 - одна тема - один вопрос. Зачем обновлять datatable, если в нём уже содержатся нужные данные (включая добавленную строку)?

Comment: у меня таймер есть, который проверяет есть ли добавленная строка

Comment: поможете с добавлением?

Comment: @propro17 - Я не вижу в вашем вопросе _таймера_! Хотите спросить про таймер - задайте **новый** вопрос. Вы и так наплодили кучу почти одинаковых вопросов. Вам там отвечали. Если что-то непонятно - там и уточняйте.

Comment: уже разобрался! спасибо!